# Is König's Property for graphs inheritable from finite subgraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, matching-theory, covering

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph. A set $C \subseteq V$ is said to be a *(vertex) cover* if $C \cap e \neq \emptyset$ for all $e\in E$. A *matching* is a set $M\subseteq E$ of pairwise disjoint edges (elements of $E$).

We say that $G$ has *König's Property* if there is a matching $M\subseteq E$ and a cover $C\subseteq V$ satisfying

1. $|C \cap e| = 1$ for all $e\in M$, and
2. $C \subseteq \bigcup M$.

**Question.** Suppose $G = (V,E)$ is a graph such that for all finite subsets $E_0\subseteq E$ the graph $(V, E_0)$ has König's Property. Does this imply that $G$ has König's Property?

Comment: If this is named after the eponym of [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kőnig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)), then note that that name is spelt with ‘ő’, not ‘ö’.

Comment: If every finite subgraph of $G$ satisfies K\"onig's Property, then $G$ has no odd cycles and is thus bipartite.  Aharoni (K\"onig's Duality Theorem For
Infinite Bipartite Graphs) proved that if $G$ is bipartite, then $G$ satisfies K\"onig's property.

Comment: @LouisD Shouldn't that be an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Just making my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423346/is-k%c3%b6nigs-property-for-graphs-inheritable-from-finite-subgraphs#comment1088018_423346) an answer as [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423346/is-k%c3%b6nigs-property-for-graphs-inheritable-from-finite-subgraphs#comment1088048_423346).)

If every finite subgraph of $G$ satisfies Kőnig's Property, then $G$ has no odd cycles and is thus bipartite. Aharoni
([König's Duality Theorem For Infinite Bipartite Graphs](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-29.1.1)) proved that if $G$ is bipartite, then $G$ satisfies Kőnig's property.

Comment: Markdown note: `K\"onig` doesn't work (it renders as `K"onig`).  Actually, [Dénes Kőnig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9nes_K%C5%91nig) is spelt like so, not König as would be produced by TeX from `K\"onig`—although apparently his father published as [Julius König](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyula_K%C5%91nig).  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Why does $G$ have no odd cycles? For example, let $G$ consist of a triangle $\{x,y,z\}$ with two extra leaves $u,v$ attached to $x$ and $y$, respectively. Then  $G$ has the Kőnig property, taking $C=\{x,y\}$ and $M=\{\{x,u\},\{y,v\}\}$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I see: $G$ itself has the Kőnig property, but not all its subgraphs. Never mind.